# Parse Account Display

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Hi I'm trying to display the logged in username in a text field. Before I started using parse I would simply say `let Account = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userName")` then say `self.textfield.text = "Account: " + Account!)`. 
Now that I'm using Parse and my username is stored in a server I'm not sure how to access the string that would be the username so I can use it in a label 
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything else is set up correctly, you should be able to use `PFUser.currentUser().username`.

Comment: For some reason I am getting a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on 'var Username = PFUser.currentUser()!.username'